# How do Digestion Buffs work?

Tags: pokemon-tabletop-united

The Player Handbook only states the following, as far as I'm aware:

> **Snacks may be consumed at any time by a Pokémon or
> Trainer as an Extended Action to grant a Digestion Buff.**
> A Pokémon or Trainer may only have one Digestion Buff
> stored at a time unless they have the Gluttony Ability,
> and **they made trade in this Buff during battle to
> use the effect of the Snack.** Berries are considered
> snacks.

Emphasis mine.
Now my question is: How long do Digestion Buffs last? Simply until they're traded in? Or does this need to happen before an extended rest is taken? Also, how long does it take to trade in a Digestion Buff? It can't be an extended action like it is to consume a snack, since it can be done during combat. Is it a free action, then? Or a standard action? Or something else still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The rules don't say the buffs end over time, so strictly speaking, they end only when you use them

The digestion buff does not have a listed duration so it lasts until it is used. However it is *intended* by the developers to only last until you take an extended rest. To quote a question asked to them in the PTU Discord ([source](https://discord.com/channels/214824499395297281/217379489615839236/722554733474349066)):

> How long are digestion buffs supposed to last?

> RAW until used, but RAI is unused ones should go away after a long rest.

---

### Digestion buffs do not list a required action to use them, so they take a free action

The buffs never say what sort of action is required to consume them, and so consuming them takes only a free action. This agrees with what the developers intended ([source](https://discord.com/channels/214824499395297281/339211455796609024/492332934317998081)):

> So there's no mention of it at all... but... what is the action to use a Digestion buff? Is it free?

> Free